# EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator; Changing SQL Server Edition

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, generator, poco

I am working through the use of EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator for the first time. I'm using SQL Server 2016.  The first attempt is attempting to use SQL CE:

```
var factory = GetDbProviderFactory();
IsSqlCe = IsSqlCeConnection(factory);
```

The error points to these lines.

It authenticates OK, but cannot find a process.  I don't have SQL CE installed.  How do I change this to connect to SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Your connection string ?

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=SIMBA;Initial Catalog=Northwind;persist security info=True;user id=lionadmin;password=*********;

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=SIMBA;Initial Catalog=Northwind;persist security info=True;user id=lionadmin;password=P596$rpss;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=NorthwindDemo" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: And you have set the connectionstringname in the database.tt file?

Comment: ConnectionStringName = "NorthwindDbContext";   // Searches for this connection string in config files listed below in the ConfigFilenameSearchOrder setting
    //ConnectionStringName is the only required setting
    // Namespace = ""; // Override the default namespace here
    DbContextName = "NorthwindDbContext";

Comment: SqlCE connection strings look like: <add name="MyDbContextSqlCE4" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|NorthwindSqlCe40.sdf" />

Comment: Update to the latest version of the template